# How to read Manifest.mbdb in cpp

Tags: iphone, c++

How to decrypt the iTune Backup file of Manifest.mbdb using CPP code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen this question?
[How to parse the Manifest.mbdb file in an iOS 4.0 iTunes Backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085153/how-to-parse-the-manifest-mbdb-file-in-an-ios-4-0-itunes-backup)

Most of the code there is Python rather than C++, but perhaps you can port it if you really need it to be C++ for some reason.

Comment: I am not familier with python and c++, is there any converting tool from python to c++?

Comment: No, not really.  You should hire someone to do it.