# How to convert a script in Python to C++?

Tags: c++, python

I need to convert python script [How to parse the Manifest.mbdb file in an iOS 4.0 iTunes Backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085153/how-to-parse-the-manifest-mbdb-file-in-an-ios-4-0-itunes-backup) to c++ code. Is there any conversion tool for that? Can anyone provide C++ code for `Manifest.mbdb` parser?

Comment: The conversion tool is you! Roll up your sleeves and get cracking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Python program to C/C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4650243/608639)

Answer (score 1):

Try [ShedSkin](http://code.google.com/p/shedskin/)

From the website:

> Shed Skin is an experimental compiler, that can translate pure, but implicitly statically typed Python programs into optimized C++. It can generate stand-alone programs or extension modules that can be imported and used in larger Python programs.

Comment: Shed Skin could help, although you'll probably have to rewrite the Python version to accommodate it's restrictions (it can't just compile any Python code). I've had good luck with it, it's a great project.

Comment: @zeekay: can it do just the "implicitly statically typed" part? Enforcing inferred type-safety on sections of Python is probably useful even if you're not planning to convert to C++!

Comment: No, it is a Python to C++ compiler. Python 3 introduced function annotations which would probably be good for that: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/

Comment: @zeekay: annotations are explicit typing, I meant something more type-inference-ey.