# How to parse the Manifest.mbdb file in an iOS 5.0 beta 2 without Manifest.mbdx

Tags: iphone, backup, ios5

I have a backup I made with iOS 5 beta2 (with iTunes 10.5 beta also). But to my surprise, it doesn't contain an mbdx file.

The `mbdb` file looks same as previous format. How can I match the file ID and file name without `Manifest.mbdx`?

Comment: iOS 5 is under NDA - you should go to devforums.apple.com and ask this question until the NDA is lifted and people can help you here.

Comment: I have updated the Python code to handle this, see the article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085153/how-to-parse-the-manifest-mbdb-file-in-an-ios-4-0-itunes-backup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hex file name in the backups folder is the SHA hash of the file path appended to the domain, with a "-" in between.  So the hash of "DomainName-/path/filename.png" will match to the correct file.

NOTE: App files have their domains prefixed with `AppDomain-`, like `AppDomain-com.supercrazyawesome.myapp`. Make sure you include that full string when calculating the SHA hash.

Comment: No problem.  Please mark this as the answer if you're happy with it. (Use the checkmark)