# get geo coordinates from iphone iOS 5.1.1; iphonels.py error-- 'Manifest.mbdx' is missing in backup folder

Tags: iphone, backup, ios5.1

This is a newb post, just fyi.

I'm trying to get location data off of my iphone for an art project.  I did a backup of my iphone and am trying to get geo coordinates from the data stored in the local copy of the backup (located in ~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/folder.  Here's what I've tried:

1. Downloaded iPhone Tracker from http://petewarden.github.com/iPhoneTracker/#faq, but when I compile and run the xcode project, I get an error that 'consolidated.db' is missing (presumably from the backup folder? I don't think I missed anything, but is there a way to generate this db file without #2 below?)
2. Downloaded and ran [iphonels.py](http://pastebin.com/hFAt0WQH) (converts file names in Backup folder to readable strings?) from the terminal, but I got the following error:
   IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Manifest.mbdx'

I think the problem is related to #2, that iOS 5.1 no longer includes Manifest.mbdx in the backup folders.  It sounds like I need to edit iphonels.py with a workaround that doesn't require this file?

Or maybe there's another way to identify which file is the database of lat and longitude points?  This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569004/how-to-parse-the-manifest-mbdb-file-in-an-ios-5-0-beta-2-without-manifest-mbdx) seems like it could be related, but I'm not really sure.

Any help is greatly appreciated.